# What is the half-inch pipe stub on my water filtration system?

Tags: plumbing, water-filtration

I am in planning stages to install whole house water filtration system. It is not a salt system.

The supplier (King Water Filtration) has a decent installation instructions, and it is clear how to install the filter, but I still have a question.

It looks like my home was readied (in 2006) for filtration install. However as you see, I have a half inch pipe sticking out and it is capped.

What is that pipe for?

[image: pipe]

Answer (score 3):

Speculatively, because that's all one can really do for a "mystery pipe picture" without the installer to ask the intent, it's for a backflush drain - fairly standard on a variety of filtration media, though probably the one most folks are familiar with is a water softener.

The fact that what **you** are planning to install is, you say, "non-salt" is irrelevant, as the "filter setup" probably defaults to being suitable for a softener (with salt) needing backwashed. That also makes it suitable for any other media that requires backwashing.

Ultimately, if you are going to use it, you'll need to sort out where it goes, most efficiently by asking the people who installed it, or consulting your house's plans, less efficiently by finding it on the other side of the wall and following it to the end.

If your filter doesn't need it, just keep ignoring it - it's managed for 17 years, it can manage a while longer not being used.

Comment: Good and reasonable speculation that it is a drain for the filter system. Even the non salt system needs a drain line. Would the drain line be PVC and not copper ? I better check that first.

Comment: Plumbers choice on the material. 1/2" is not really made as "drain pipe" but does seem to be a common size for filter drains. Should go to an air-gap and a (normal drain-pipe-size) trap (or floor drain or sump) if connected to the sewage system; could be as easy as pour some water in and listen carefully. Then again, I had to convert one that was "cleverly" run outside onto the lawn "to save the septic system" when the sewer came through at that house, as the sewer people did not approve of that discharge. So if plumbed creatively it might be more of a hunt.

Comment: Or could it be the kitchen bypass, sometimes used to avoid drinking the high salt water from salt based softener.

Comment: I'd *expect* that to already be connected from the inlet side to the cold water line at the sink faucet. But sure, an additional possibility.

Comment: I wish I could take X-ray to see the pipes. I am certain to have one 1 inch or larger pipe going into home from outside (exactly at the hight of the picture I took from inside), what it does after that who knows.

Comment: There are things that purport to allow you to "see" pipes and wires in the wall (obviously not X-Ray based) typically marketed as "wall scanners" or "advanced stud-finders" - I have not succumbed to their marketing and the high prices that pay their marketing people, since I remain skeptical of their real-world performance. If they lived up to the hype they would do what you ask. That's a big if.

Comment: Any chance it was originally plumbed for the water heater and the location changed at a later date?